# Как найти сумму чисел между a и b?

Tags: циклы, c++

Как найти сумму чисел между a и b (вводятся с клавиатуры)? Вот моё решение:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    cin >> a >> b;

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
    {
        a = a + 1;
        sum = sum + a;
    }

    cout << sum;
}
```

Пожалуйста, укажите на ошибку. Например, при вводе 5 и 8 выдаёт 21, а должно 13.

**UPD**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    cin >> a >> b;

    int sum = 0;

    while (a < b - 1)
    {
        a = a + 1;
        sum = sum + a;
    }
     cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: посчитайте число итераций. и зачем вам **i**? избавьтесь от нее.

Comment: Лучше оставить `a` и `b` постоянными, и суммировать `i`.

---
Кстати, а почему вы сначала увеличиваете, а потом прибавляете?

---
И ещё: 5 + 6 + 7 = 18, 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 26, откуда взялось 13?

Comment: Имеются ввиду числа МЕЖДУ a и b. То есть при вводе 5 и 8, нужно посчитать сумму 6 и 7.

Comment: Судя по вашему заданию, вы _учитесь_ программировать. Разжёвывать основы как-то не хочется, это задача вашего учителя. Попробуйте в уме прокрутить программу, станет понятнее.

Попробуйте думать не о _значениях_ переменных, а о их _смысле_. Какой _смысл_ переменной `i`? `a`? Если вы сможете ответить на эти вопросы, вам ваш код станет понятнее. И вы чему-то научитесь.

Comment: А вы попробуйте сформулировать, всё же. Какой смысл переменной `i`?

Comment: Не, не счётчик. Счётчик начинался бы от 0 или там от 1, а у вас он от `a`. Вторая попытка?

---
Тут ограничение количества комментариев, так что вам придётся удалять свои старые комментарии, чтобы ответить.

Comment: Тогда не знаю. Подскажете?

Comment: Не смогу. Потому что в вашем коде он вообще никакого смысла не несёт, отсюда и проблема, и непонимание.

Comment: Я бы сначала придумал ему смысл, а потом исправил код так, чтобы этот смысл выполнялся. Например: пусть `i` у нас пробегает слагаемые, которые нужны в результирующей сумме. Тогда `i` должно пробегать значения от наименьшего слагаемого (какое оно?) до наибольшего (какое оно?), а внутри цикла мы должны просто (что?).

Дальше включайте мозг сами.

Comment: @wmt: Угу, лучше, должно быть правильно. Но я бы всё же сделал с циклом по `i`, потому что у вас сейчас `a` используется для двух разных целей: сначала это «нижняя граница», а в середине первой итерации цикла она превращается в «текущее слагаемое». Переменные нынче дешёвые, не жалейте. Я лично пользуюсь принципом «один смысл — одна переменная», так выходит гораздо проще.

Comment: @wmt: угу, уже давненько подтормаживает.

Менять смысл переменных на ходу — плохая практика, вы можете и не уследить за тем, в каком случае какой из смыслов актуален. Особенно это становится очевидным в больших проектах.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка в том, что циклы для вашей задачи не нужны. Ответ находится одной формулой `(b - a - 1) * (a + b) / 2`.

Comment: @dzhioev: Ну, это если знать арифметические прогрессии.

Comment: По-моему, формула работает. Но осталось два вопроса:
1) как решить задачу именно циклом
2) как сделать, чтобы считалась сумма чисел МЕЖДУ a и b (при вводе 5 и 8 нужно посчитать сумму 6 и 7)

Comment: @wmt, на оба вопроса ответ один - напишите программу. подсказки вам дали. за вас писать тут никто не будет, во-первых, это противоречит правилам, во-вторых, вы ничему не научитесь, в третьих, что-нибудь про деньги - с этим на биржу фрилансеров.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = a + 1; i < b; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```